# Vmware Player - guest windows lose full-screen after host is locked

Tags: multiple-monitors, vmware, fullscreen

I have a problem with VMware Player - when I lock my computer then VMware Player guest loses full-screen and second monitor is closed so after switching back all applications are on primary monitor.

Is there any way to prevent this? For example to let guest system be minimized like in case of clicking on minimize button in top VMware panel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I have been able to work around this is to minimize the guess before locking the computer.  Once you resume, just re-maximize the guest and it should still be in full screen (it even works with multiple monitors cycling).

I am just really dissapointed that this made it into v4 since v3 did not have this issue and even more dissapointed that the newest release (v4.0.1) did not handle this.